# Component keeps making api calls with custom axios hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a dashboard component which renders some widget. It fetches widget data from four different APIs.

*Dashbaord.jsx*

```
import { Box, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import { useAxios } from '../../api/use-axios';
import { NewWidget } from '../../components/widget/NewWidget';
import ApiConfig from '../../api/api-config';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { response: studentResponse } = useAxios({
    url: ApiConfig.STUDENTS.base,
  });

  const { response: courseResponse } = useAxios({
    url: ApiConfig.COURSES.base,
  });

  const { response: feesResponse } = useAxios({
    url: ApiConfig.FEES.total,
  });

  return (
    <Box padding={2} width="100%">
      <Stack direction={'row'} justifyContent="space-between" gap={2} mb={10}>
        <NewWidget type={'student'} counter={studentResponse?.data?.length} />
        <NewWidget type={'course'} counter={courseResponse?.data?.length} />
        <NewWidget type={'earning'} counter={feesResponse?.data} />
        <NewWidget type={'teacher'} counter={studentResponse?.data?.length} />
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
};
export default Dashboard;
```

It uses a custom hook `useAxios` to make API calls.

*use-axios.jsx*

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

export const useAxios = (axiosParams) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async (params) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.request({
        ...params,
        method: params.method || 'GET',
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
        headers: {
          accept: 'application/json',
        },
      });
      setResponse(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(axiosParams);
  }, [axiosParams]); // execute once only

  return { response, error, loading };
};
```

api-config.js

```
export default {
  COURSES: {
    base: '/courses',
  },
  FEES: {
    base: '/fees',
    total: '/fees/total',
  },
  STUDENTS: {
    base: '/students',
  },
};
```

But somehow, It keeps rendering and also all the responses form APIs, it logs to `undefiend`.

I tried removing dependency `axiosPamras` from `useEffect` in `useAxios`, It stops making multiple requests but still it shows `dependency warning` and also response is still `undefined`.

---

*Update:
`undefined` error is fixed, I wasn't passing authorization token. :(*

*But still when `axiosParams` added to dependency it keeps calling apis in loop*

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the way you're calling `useAxios`. You're passing an object literal each time, eg

```
const { response: studentResponse } = useAxios({
  url: ApiConfig.STUDENTS.base,
});
```

Because you're calling with an object, equality of this is determined by reference - and passing an object literal is a new reference on each render, even though it's "the same" object as far as you're concerned. So the `useEffect` with `axiosParams` as its dependency will rerun each time, hence the repeated sending of requests.

The easiest solution in this case is probably to extract these objects to constants which are stored outside the component - they come from an `ApiConfig` object so it seems unlikely this will change while the application is running. And doing this will mean the reference will always be the same and thus not trigger your `useEffect` to rerun.

That is, put this outside the component:

```
const STUDENT_AXIOS_CONFIG = { url: ApiConfig.STUDENTS.base };
```

and the same for the other 2 sets of axios Params. Then inside the component do:

```
const { response: studentResponse } = useAxios(STUDENT_AXIOS_CONFIG);
```

and of course do the same for the other 2 calls.

Comment: Is there any better to store mapping of resources to url? Because let's say I want to get total fees collected. So, `{ FEES: { GET_TOTAL: '/fees/total' }` It doesn't look right. How to have such mapping? Or Should I create class which have methods and returns these configs, like `class Fees { getTotalFees () { return {....config here }}}` It will re-render again when method is called, right? :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm afraid. But anyway I hope I've explain what the problem is, even if your eventual solution has to be slightly different from what I've proposed: by passing in the `axiosParams` as object literals, they will be considered different on each render. Another alternative, depending on what is in your `axiosParams`, would be to change the dependency array so that it lists the properties as separate dependencies (assuming they're all primitive values like strings or numbers) - ie replace `[axiosParams]` with `[axiosParams.url, axiosParams.somethingElse, ...]`

Comment: I tried it still give the same warning `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'axiosParams'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

Comment: Well OK that won't work without some rewriting then. But I didn't think you were bothered by these warnings since you are clearly ignoring the one it should be giving you about `fetchData` not being a dependency...

Comment: In any case, having reread your first comment, I think you're worrying over nothing. Nothing in my answer suggested rewriting your `api-config.js`. That is completely fine. As I said in my answer, you just need to pull those "constant" object literals you are passing to `useAxios` inside your component, to outside of the component.